# Bionic: apt-get install docker-ce always hangs

Tags: 18.04, apt, docker

I've just upgraded a system from xenial to bionic.  We were running docker under xenial, so in an attempt to start clean I went through and `apt-get purge` all the xenial docker packages.  I also removed `/var/lib/docker` [as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798076/how-to-clean-up-docker).

Before I install `docker-ce` under bionic, I check `updatedb` and `locate` / `rm` any other docker cruft (including package archives in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`... so I think I'm starting clean).

I also:

- added the new `download.docker.com` key with `apt-key`
- put `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

When I run `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-cli`, my system hangs here:

```
Preparing to unpack .../5-docker-ce_5%3a19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Setting up aufs-tools (1:4.9+20170918-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up containerd.io (1.2.13-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/containerd.service → /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service.
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
Setting up docker-ce-cli (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Setting up pigz (2.4-1) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
```

At this point I do a `ps -elf` and see that there is a docker process running... killing it unhangs the install, but `sudo dkpg -a --configure` continues to hang.

I'm running bionic with kernel `4.15.0-101-generic`.

How can I get docker fully functional on this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was I had to change `docker daemon` to `dockerd` in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/service-overrides.conf`.

After changing this, I got docker installed as usual with `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli`.